# Occasionally web server unable to write on storage/logs on production environment

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

Using AWS as my host, occasionally the production server is unable to write logs to the `storage/logs/*` and causes my application to white-screen. I don't sudo when git pull'ing and my storage owner/group/permissions are as follows:

`drwxrwxr-x  6 apache apache`

There doesn't seem to be any sort of pattern as to when the white-screen'ing happens. It's without any sort of admin pulling or messing with files, it happens "naturally". Is there a small daemon or something that could be changing permissions?

Comment: I have the same problem, but mine is produced everything I reboot apache web server

Answer (score 0):

The problem was supervisor's running as root which would overwrite logs as root.

In my supervisor program's .conf:

`[program:my_programs_name]
user=ec2-user`